# How to check if Two Arrays Have Same Elements Regardless of Their Index Position

Tags: php

can you please let me know how I can check if two arrays have same elements and return true or false regardless of their elements index position?
as you can see the `$a==$b` is not doing this

```
$a = array("apple","banana", "strawberry");
$b = array("strawberry", "apple","banana");
if($a==$b){
   echo "yes";
}else{
 echo "no";
}
```

Comment: use array_diff function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array Diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) :

```
$a = array("apple","banana", "strawberry");
$b = array("strawberry", "apple","banana");


$result = array_diff($a, $b);

if(count($result) > 0){
   echo "yes";
}else{
   echo "no";
}
```

Comment: There is no need to sort them, if using `array_diff()`, that is just redundant.

Comment: This is wrong for two reasons: 1) it should be `count($result) == 0` to match what the OP asks, 2) you cannot rely on one diff alone to tell you if two arrays have same elements. we need `diff (a, b) == diff (b, a) == []`, otherwise adding "oranges" to array $b will still tell us yes, which is not the OP asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Just enclose your array objects in `sort()` function while comparing them.

```
$a = array("apple","banana", "strawberry");
$b = array("strawberry", "apple","banana");
if(sort($a) == sort($b)){
    echo "yes";
}else{
    echo "no";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `sort()` both the arrays and then check for equality. Like this:

```
<?php

$a=array("apple","banana", "strawberry");
$b=array("strawberry", "apple","banana");

$a = sort($a);
$b = sort($b);
if($a==$b){
   echo "yes";
}else{
 echo "no";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **array_diff()** function.

```
$a = array("apple","banana", "strawberry");
$b = array("strawberry", "apple","banana");
$diff = array_diff($a, $b);
if(count($diff) > 0){
   echo "yes";
}
else{
   echo "no";
}
print_r($diff);
```

If **$diff** returns an empty array, it means there are no differences between **$a** and **$b**.

Otherwise, **$diff** returns the elements which are differents.

Check the manual, [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

Comment: Your's is the best solution here so far.

Comment: I am not OP, and I did upvote your answer. Still, to make it complete, I would suggest that you add a line to check length of `$diff` and give output as `yes` or `no`. Currently, this only gives `Array()` as output.

Comment: @PrateekGupta Made it!